# Missing date identification

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm relatively early in SQL learning. I have made some data which has records where the date is missing. I want to capture as an output records that show the missing dates and the associated department name affected.

output of missing dates expected to be like

```
Date        DepartmentID
2023-11-03  3001
2023-11-03  4001
2023-11-06  1001
2023-11-06  2001
2023-11-07  1001
2023-11-07  2001
2023-11-07  4001
2023-11-09  4001
```

My table setup

```
Create table Departments (date date,DepartmentID int, Name text);

insert into Departments values
(to_date('1.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('1.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('1.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('1.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),4001,'ds'),
(to_date('2.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('2.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('2.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('2.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),4001,'ds'),
(to_date('3.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('3.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('4.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('4.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('4.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('4.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),4001,'ds'),
(to_date('5.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('5.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('5.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('5.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),4001,'ds'),
(to_date('6.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('6.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),4001,'ds'),
(to_date('7.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('8.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('8.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('8.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting'),
(to_date('8.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),4001,'ds'),
(to_date('9.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),1001,'SRO'),
(to_date('9.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),2001,'Drs'),
(to_date('9.11.23','DD.MM,YY'),3001,'Accounting');
```

So far my logic is the following sql whilst following instructions from [here](https://medium.com/codex/fill-gaps-in-time-series-with-this-simple-trick-in-sql-81ac655e5ad7)

```
with lastdate as
(select max(date) as Maxdate from Departments)

  select date, 
  --lead(date),
  select maxdate from lastdate OVER(partition by date ORDER BY date) as Next_Date 
  from Departments
```

But this gives errors as seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cpryg0uY)

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select" LINE 6:   select maxdate from
> lastdate OVER(partition by date ORDER ...
> ^

This is in postgres. Things I'm confused about

1. How do run a CTE and have an OVER statement run along side against the CTE
2. Best way to approach this problem.

Comment: The syntax is invalid. What you posted include `select date, select maxdate from lastdate...` which is invalid. It also includes two SELECTs inside a CTE.

Comment: Read the manual on window functions? Get the correct syntax?https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html

Comment: The CTE establishes a view named lastdate with a column called maxdate and a single row. So, `select maxdate from lastdate` is possible, but it must be included in parentheses, if you want to use this in the main query's select clause. It will return one value, namely the maximum date found in the table. You *can* invoke a window function on this value, but no matter if it's `MIN OVER` or `MAX OVER` you will still get that one value. E.g. `max((select maxdate from lastdate)) OVER(partition by date ORDER BY date) as Next_Date`. That gets the syntax right, but is obviously a wrong approach.

Comment: On a side note: This is not really a departments table, where I would expect one row per department, but some kind of departemnt history table (?) where we see what a department was called on a specific day. So, this seems to ask for a better table name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, [anti-joins](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/rise-of-the-anti-join) are faster than `except`: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VVYy02xJ)

```sql
with required_dept_date as (
  select distinct DepartmentID, 
         generate_series('2023.11.01'::date,'2023.11.10','1 day')::date AS date
  from Departments)
select required_dept_date.*
from required_dept_date natural left join Departments
where Departments.DepartmentID is null order by 1,2;
```

It takes 0.14s. You pick the period you want to zoom in on by setting the `start` and `stop` dates in [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). When used in the select list, it'll spawn all required dates for all possible departments, which you join with your table and pick out the dates and depts that your table didn't have a match for (`Departments is null`).

Same using `except` will be a [few times slower](https://dbfiddle.uk/yozhcFF5):

```sql
select distinct DepartmentID, 
       generate_series('2023.11.01'::date,'2023.11.10','1 day')::date AS date
from Departments
except
select DepartmentID, date
from Departments;
```

It's an implementation detail, so it can change in the future - after all, both forms express the same concept. Alternative forms of the anti-join include [`not exists`, `<>all()`, `not in`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html), and PostgreSQL planner has had this ["preference"](https://google.com/search?q=postgres%20antijoin) since [at least version 8.4](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) (still has in current 16.1). Other RDBMS won't necessarily have that bias.

To get all dates instead of a specific period, you can generate them based on `min()` and `max()` separately, or just plug uncorrelated [scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) directly where you need these values:

```sql
with required_dept_date as (
  select distinct DepartmentID, 
         generate_series((select min(date) from Departments),
                         (select max(date) from Departments),
                         '1 day')::date AS date
  from Departments)
select required_dept_date.*
from required_dept_date left join Departments using (DepartmentID,date)
where Departments.DepartmentID is null;
```

These are very flexible and intuitive, but it's always best to make sure you don't query too many things, too many times, so it might be better to try and get these values in a single scan.

In case you want to ignore dates when nobody reported anything (November 3rd and 7th in your fiddle): instead of generating the full calendar, extract all distinct dates that you have and combine them with all distinct depts:

```sql
with required_dept as (
  select distinct DepartmentID from Departments)
,required_dept_date as (
  select distinct date,rd.DepartmentID from Departments, required_dept AS rd)
select required_dept_date.*
from Departments natural right join required_dept_date
where Departments is null;
```

Note the `a natural join b` and `a join b using (c1,c2)` - these are alternative forms of `a join b on a.c1=b.c1 and a.c2=b.c2`. `Natural` automatically detects all matching column names and uses them to join on, while `using` matches columns from the list in parentheses. It's important to make sure you're preparing and naming the columns for that purpose (cte, subquery, aliasing, schema setup) - otherwise you risk accidentally joining on columns you you didn't plan to use, but happened to have matching names.

In any case, you might want to [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) to get one [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.2.1.1.1) of all missing departments for each date:

```sql
with required_dept_date as (
  select distinct DepartmentID, 
         generate_series((select min(date) from Departments),
                         (select max(date) from Departments),
                         '1 day')::date AS date
  from Departments)
select required_dept_date.date,
       array_agg(required_dept_date.departmentid 
                 order by required_dept_date.departmentid) AS missing
from required_dept_date left join Departments using (DepartmentID,date)
where Departments.DepartmentID is null
group by 1 order by 1;
```

| date | missing |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | {700,2001,3001,4001,5001,6001} |
| 2023-11-02 | {700,1001,3001,4001,5001,6001} |
| 2023-11-03 | {700,1001,2001,3001,4001,5001,6001} |
| 2023-11-04 | {700,1001,2001,4001,5001,6001} |
| 2023-11-05 | {700,1001,2001,3001,5001,6001} |
| 2023-11-06 | {700,1001,2001,3001,4001,6001} |
| 2023-11-07 | {700,1001,2001,3001,4001,5001,6001} |
| 2023-11-08 | {700,1001,2001,3001,4001,5001} |
| 2023-11-09 | {1001,2001,3001,4001,5001,6001} |

Comment: I've decided to downvote this answer for the reason that it is giving bad advice. We strive to write our queries as readable and thus maintainable as possible. Only when we run into performance issues would we usually sacrifice readability for speed. And be aware that you are optimizing for a particular DBMS and even for a particular version of that DBMS and should optimally replace the less readable query by a proper one as soon as the DBMS vendor has solved the underlying issue...

Comment: ...In this particular case, there is nothing to optimize. The query you run first, will be slower, as there is no data in the cache yet. So if you run the queris in opposite order, the results will be vice versa: suddenly my query is the faster one: https://dbfiddle.uk/NNbvyo8Q. Admittedly `EXCEPT` is a method rarely used. It can make a query very readable, but you'd rather see `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` most often...

Comment: ...Today's DBMS optimizers are very good, but while ideally all these queries should lead to the same, optimal execution plan, they don't. For this small data set at least, `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` outperform my `EXCEPT` query and the suggested anti-join query by far. `NOT IN` seems to be the best choice for this data, outperforming even `NOT EXISTS`. That `NOT IN` and not `NOT EXISTS` lead to sligtly different plans here speaks against the optimizer, but this will probably get fixed in some future PostgreSQL version.

Comment: @Dan: Be aware that it is usually very dangerous to use `NATURAL` joins. It works here, because we are only working with one table and care about the column naming of the on-the-fly view, but when used in another context, natural joins make your queries subject to failure, because it joins on columns that happen to have the same name. If a DBA decided that all tables get an additional column last_update to record the time the row was last written to, for instance, all natural joins will break and return less or no rows at all...

Comment: ...Professional SQL developers agree that natural joins should not have made it into the SQL standard. `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is another thing you should never use. They can make queries extremely hard to read. Always write your joins in an order where you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead. As mentioned, I recommend you don't use the anti-join pattern either. If you want to make sure a row does not exist in a table, use the straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. (The latter has a problem when the looked-up data contains nulls, though, so it is usually safer to use `NOT EXISTS`)...

Comment: ...Another thing is conversions: Don't use inappropriate data types that you must convert. This is a general rule that mainly affects the database design (column data types), but also applies to literals used in queries. Don't use a string for dates that you tell the DBMS to convert. While yyyy-mm-dd is unambiguous, I am not aware that PostgreSQL actually guarantees that it will always convert this string properly. So instad of `'some string'::date` use date literals in the first place. They start with the key word `DATE` and get followed by the aforementioned date format: `DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: At last: Avoid reading the same table again and again. In the third query the departments tabe is read thrice, only to get aggregated again and again. Look here for a solution and see the difference in run time: https://dbfiddle.uk/Zq7Bpe4o (I've created many more rows to make the difference more obvious.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for taking the time to write this out. Your feedback is constructive and I've edited my post to address it:
**1)** I opened by saying this is specific to PostgreSQL. I could add [it's been the case for a while](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) and that it's an implementation detail that can change in future versions. For now, the choice between portability and performance is down to OP. Warning added.

Comment: **2)** It's hard to disagree that ideally, all these constructs should be equally optimizable. Consideration of how things are executed goes against the idea of SQL being declarative. Added a point on that, too. **3)** There's a bad use case for everything: `natural join` sure has plenty, but a cte where you prepare and name the column for that exact purpose, isn't one of them. I strongly disagree a useful feature should be boycotted or not made available in the first place, because someone *can and will* misuse it. Knives cut both bread and people - that's a universal risk. Warning added.

Comment: **4)** `Right join` rides the same cart as `except`. Conceptually, it's supposed to be the reverse of `left join` and ideally, planner should optimize it however you flip it. That being said, it's not the case, similar to how `except` doesn't result in an anti-join even though intuitively it should - implementation details. I've swapped it for a `left`. **5)** `min()` and `max()` in the third query pop from index, assuming you have one - but the whole thing is there just to show off scalar subqueries. Minimizing scans is a good advice - added that too.

Comment: **6)** There's [absolutely no difference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) between `date 'today'`,`'today'::date` and `cast('today' as date)` - if you want to be *more sure*, use `to_date('2023-11-05','YYYY-MM-DD')` - specifying the mask explicitly makes this independent from locale settings like `DateStyle`. I've added the part about `to_date()`.

Comment: **7)** One-run benchmark isn't really a benchmark - that's true, and caching behaviour certainly didn't help. Still, `except` *is and has been slower*. I've added a looped, alternating [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/yozhcFF5) on a larger sample. Anti-join proves to be reliably faster. I join you in hoping this will change at some point.

Comment: **8)** `not exists`, `<>all()`, `not in` and asymmetric `join...where other is null` are all anti-joins - specifically, syntactic methods of encouraging the planner to apply it, which you could say about any SQL construct. I showed a single example, linked a more in-depth resource on the matter that also addresses alternatives, left a phrase to search for. It makes little sense to re-do yet another full postgres anti-join revisit here but I updated that part to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Thank your for looking into this in detail and improve your answer. I've removed my downvote of course.

Answer (score -1):

You want to find departments and dates that are missing from the departments table. So create a table with all dates and departments that you expect and subtract the ones that exist.

```
with 
  all_dates (date) as
  (
    select generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') from departments
  ),
  all_departments as
  (
    select distinct departmentid from departments
  )
select all_dates.date, all_departments.departmentid
from all_dates cross join all_departments
except
select date, departmentid
from departments
order by date, departmentid;
```

Instead of `EXCEPT` you can use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` here. Which to use is a matter of personal choice. They all do the same: remove rows from the result that exist in the table. I've added the two alternatives to my demo below.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/loto1rbo