# Find each table schema, name and column that doesn't contain a specific value in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, execute, sql-except

```sql
    DROP FUNCTION pcm_search_columns(text,name[],name[]);

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pcm_search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{}'
    )
    RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
    AS $$
    begin
      FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
        JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
          (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
        JOIN information_schema.table_privileges p ON
          (t.table_name=p.table_name AND t.table_schema=p.table_schema
              AND p.privilege_type='SELECT')
        JOIN information_schema.schemata s ON
          (s.schema_name=t.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name='el_div')
        AND (c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema) OR haystack_schema='{}')
        AND (t.table_type='BASE TABLE')
        AND (c.column_name='grp')
     LOOP
    for rowctid in
    execute ('SELECT id FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
      )
    LOOP
      --uncomment next line to get some progress report
      --RAISE NOTICE 'hit in %.%', schemaname, tablename;
      RETURN NEXT;
      END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
    END;
    $$ language plpgsql;

    select * from pcm_search_columns('5','{}');
```

I made this function that finds rows in column `grp` in table `el_div`. I need an extra column showing `rowvalue`. I also need to be able to use it to get tables *missing* this value.

Comment: [Here's a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77446387/5298879). If you want the opposite of that, you can just do `select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where (table_schema,table_name) not in (select table_schema,table_name from find_anywhere('needle'));` or use any other [except/anti-join construct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77556662/5298879).